# Clipping features with the attributes of another feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, clip, catchment

I have a vector polygon for a catchment which contains numerous subbasins. In addition, I also, possess another vector polygon showing the impervious areas of the catchment.

What I want to do is determine just how much of each subbasin is impervious. To do so, I planned to clip the impervious area vector with the boundaries of the subbasins contained by the cat catchment vector. How can this be achieved?

I've tried using the clip function with both datasets as they were, but that hasn't worked. I also attempted to use the clip function with the vector files converted to polyline, and still not the result I was looking for.

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried and what software you are using.

Comment: What is your desired result? A percentage column in your subbasin feature class? In any case try starting with [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm)

Comment: Thank you! It turns out Intersect was actually what I was looking for. Yes, what I want is to have a percentage column in my subbasin feature class.